# Why is the order by not working in my query with a Pivot Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
Data

Client     Cluster     Vol
----------------------------
A1         AS          23 
A2         AEA         24
A3         HT          48
A4         PT          25
A4         AES         25
```

```
Query

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT client, cluster_log, sum(CS_VOL)
FROM FID            
GROUP BY client, cluster_log
PIVOT
(
sum(CS_VOL)
FOR CLUSTER_LOG IN ('AS','AEA','HT','PT','AES') 
)
ORDER BY SUM(CS_VOL);
```

Hello All,

the order by is throwing an error for this query. Can you please assist?
I realise the pivot is not showing the CS_VOL but is breaking the CS_VOL into cluster_log (which it is meant to do) but I would like to order the pivot (cluster_log) by CS_VOL but I get the error 'Unknown identifier' for CS_VOL in the order by.

The other option would be to bring the CS_VOL in addition to the Cluster_log and order on that but I am not sure how to bring that in to the pivot.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the desired output from your query? (It's not easy to tell - if we just run the query as written, without the `ORDER BY` clause, we find several other mistakes.)

Comment: Hi @AM_86 it would be nice to get some feedback from you ? Are the answers you have received ok ? Helpful ? Not ok ? Amazingly what you were looking for ? Commenting, up voting and accepting an answer would be a nice thing from your side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT client,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CLUSTER_LOG = 'AS' THEN CS_VOL END) as vol_as,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CLUSTER_LOG = 'AEA' THEN CS_VOL END) as vol_aea,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CLUSTER_LOG = 'HT' THEN CS_VOL END) as vol_ht,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CLUSTER_LOG = 'PT' THEN CS_VOL END) as vol_pt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CLUSTER_LOG = 'AES' THEN CS_VOL END) as vol_aes
FROM FID            
GROUP BY client
ORDER BY SUM(CS_VOL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT client
             , cluster_log
             , CS_VOL
             , sum(CS_VOL) test
      FROM FID
      group by client
               , cluster_log
               , CS_VOL)
PIVOT 
(
  sum(CS_VOL)
  FOR cluster_log
  IN ('AS','AEA','HT','PT','AES')
)
order by test desc
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT client
             , cluster_log
             , sum(CS_VOL) CS_VOL
             , sum(CS_VOL) test
      FROM FID
      group by client
               , cluster_log)
PIVOT 
(
  sum(CS_VOL)
  FOR cluster_log
  IN ('AS','AEA','HT','PT','AES')
)
order by test desc
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b18c2c648f84756e101b3ce512a7c72)

Answer (score 2):

Ordering by `SUM(CS_VOL)` does not make sense as you are converting the values in rows into multiple columns and it is unclear how such an order would be applied.

You can just do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   FID            
PIVOT  (
  SUM(CS_VOL) FOR CLUSTER_LOG IN ('AS','AEA','HT','PT','AES')
);
```

Which for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fid ( Client, Cluster_Log, CS_Vol ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'AS',  23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'AEA', 24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'HT',  48 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 'PT',  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 'AES', 25 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CLIENT | 'AS' | 'AEA' | 'HT' | 'PT' | 'AES'
> :----- | ---: | ----: | ---: | ---: | ----:
> A2     | null |    24 | null | null |  null
> A3     | null |  null |   48 | null |  null
> A1     |   23 |  null | null | null |  null
> A4     | null |  null | null |   25 |    25
> ```

You don't need an `ORDER BY` clause on the `SUM` as these values will be in columns and not in rows (since they were the subject of the `PIVOT`). If you want an `ORDER BY` clause then you could `ORDER BY client` (or one of the other columns you've just generated).

If you do want to `ORDER BY` the total across all the columns then just add the values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   FID            
PIVOT  (
  SUM(CS_VOL) FOR CLUSTER_LOG IN (
    'AS'  AS "AS",
    'AEA' AS AEA,
    'HT'  AS HT,
    'PT'  AS PT,
    'AES' AS AES
  )
)
ORDER BY COALESCE("AS",0)+COALESCE(AEA,0)+COALESCE(HT,0)+COALESCE(PT,0)+COALESCE(AES,0);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CLIENT |   AS |  AEA |   HT |   PT |  AES
> :----- | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> A1     |   23 | null | null | null | null
> A2     | null |   24 | null | null | null
> A3     | null | null |   48 | null | null
> A4     | null | null | null |   25 |   25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eedfb1ddd8e1d6f58b4e88e23fb72c83)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with fid as
(
select 'A1' client, 'AS' Cluster_log, 23 cs_vol from dual union
select 'A2', 'AEA', 24 from dual union
select 'A3', 'HT',  48 from dual union
select 'A4', 'PT',  25 from dual union
select 'A4', 'AES', 25 from dual
)
, pivot_query as
(
SELECT *
FROM FID            
PIVOT
(
sum(CS_VOL)
FOR CLUSTER_LOG IN ('AS','AEA','HT','PT','AES') 
)
)
select pivot_query.* 
, (select sum(cs_vol) from fid where fid.client = pivot_query.client) sum_cs_vol
from pivot_query
order by sum_cs_vol
;
```